# Windows Mobile 6.5 - camera life preview and image capture using my own dialog

Tags: windows, mobile, camera

Im writing an application for workers in our factory and one of requirements is that they should be able to take images using camera integrated in PDA with WM6.5.
The main difficulty is, that thay MUST NEVER EVER be able to enter windows, Start button,  desktop etc. They are allowed ONLY to see my fullscreen application.

I succesfully deactivated BlueTooth + red, green and volume buttons (if you are interested, im pasting links here)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=546737

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431750.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/a4f9f41d-47a8-4080-8613-2c2ddcf4c012/

And now I have to implement the camera function. But as CameraCaptureDialog opens a new dialog and shows start button, task bar and allows user to open list of applications, I must not use it.

I must create my own dialog that will show the Live Preview in a panel or in an imageBox and photo will be taken using a button.

I searched the whole internet and found only DirectShow.NETCF (but people do not recommend it) and CameraCaptureDialog.

Can I somehow redirect the CameraCaptureDialog to my dialog? Or can I access camera directly via .NET framework? Or can I modify the CameraCaptureDialog not to show Start button, menu etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a bit of a challenge. I agree that Directshow is a questionable solution, but it may be your only option. I did get http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/directshownetcf/ to work, but only on low resolutions.

A better option might be to find a device that does not show the menu bar/start button. AFAIK, the HTC HD2 has a very clean Cameracapturedialog..

Good luck.